# Can not add soft credit to an organization

Tags: civicontribute, soft-credit

Has anyone seen an instance where a contribution can not be edited to add a soft credit to an organization?

I can add individuals, and it's only happening on the contributions from some contribution (donation) pages but not others. I've not been able to replicate on demo, but since it's only happening on some contribution pages I'm not sure exactly how to replicate.

Environment: Drupal 7.32 CiviCRM 4.6.15

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this as well. I'm running Wordpress 4.4.4 and Civi 4.6.4. I can add soft credits to individuals all I want but I cannot mix individuals and organizations soft credits in the same donation. Or so I thought, after messing around for a bit I found that if I removed the campaign that was set and the contribution page that was set (and saved the record). Then went back in I could add the organization soft credit.

I could then go back into the donation and add back in the campaign or the online fundraising page. This part was wonky and most successful when I added the campaign first, saved then went back and added the online page.

I was also successful mixing soft credits on a fresh donation when I only had the campaign set and no online fundraising page.

My take away, online fundraising pages in the set in the donation have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM added a validation step in 4.7.4 to prevent attributing soft credits to organizations if the contribution is tied to a contribution page using the "Honoree" section: [Contribution soft credit does not save for differenty contact type](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18102)

However as of 4.7.18 at least, there's an issue in which validation errors on the soft-credit "Contact" field are not correctly displayed to the user. This is explained here: [Soft credit "contact" field validation errors do not display](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20472)